# Flutter FCM issue-Firebase push notification The Internet connection appears to be offline

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification

I am using `firebase_core: ^2.16.0` `firebase_messaging: ^14.6.8`  `flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.1` IOS test phone.

*Xcode build done.                                           13.5s
Installing and launching...
(lldb) 2023-09-26 16:57:22.138952+0930 Runner[1611:453109] [VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(35)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
Warning: Unable to create restoration in progress marker file
10.15.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
10.15.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...
Connection 1: received failure notification
Connection 1: failed to connect 1:50, reason -1
Connection 1: encountered error(1:50)
Task <439DD375-848C-4E57-B124-9D42480BE3EC>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1009 [1:50])
Task <439DD375-848C-4E57-B124-9D42480BE3EC>.<1> finished with error [-1009] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x2839040f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=unsatisfied (Denied over Wi-Fi interface), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <439DD375-848C-4E57-B124-9D42480BE3EC>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <439DD375-848C-4E57-B124-9D42480BE3EC>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/resident-app-v3/installations/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/resident-app-v3/installations/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
Connection 2: received failure notification
Connection 2: failed to connect 1:50, reason -1
Connection 2: encountered error(1:50)
Task .<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1009 [1:50])
Task .<1> finished with error [-1009] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x283903f90 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=unsatisfied (Denied over Wi-Fi interface), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask .<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57665/-FJ42-4xhtk=/ws
Syncing files to device ...
flutter: User granted notification permission
Connection 3: received failure notification
Connection 3: failed to connect 1:50, reason -1
Connection 3: encountered error(1:50)
Task <4A084F00-723D-4B79-BA81-9840FF89E35C>.<2> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1009 [1:50])
Task <4A084F00-723D-4B79-BA81-9840FF89E35C>.<2> finished with error [-1009] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x2839755f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=unsatisfied (Denied over Wi-Fi interface), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <4A084F00-723D-4B79-BA81-9840FF89E35C>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <4A084F00-723D-4B79-BA81-9840FF89E35C>.<2>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
FLTFirebaseMessaging: An error occurred while calling method Messaging#getToken, errorOrNil => {
NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin";
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin";
NSLocalizedDescription = "The Internet connection appears to be offline.";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=unsatisfied (Denied over Wi-Fi interface), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}";
"_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey" = "LocalDataTask <4A084F00-723D-4B79-BA81-9840FF89E35C>.<2>";
"_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey" =     (
"LocalDataTask <4A084F00-723D-4B79-BA81-9840FF89E35C>.<2>"
);
"_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey" = 50;
"_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey" = 1;
}
Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] The Internet connection appears to be offline.
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)

#2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:510:43)

#3      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:248:11)

#4      NotificationService.notificationInit (package:resident_app_v3/app/services/notification_service.dart:47:13)*

When the app is first installed and launched, I encounter two pop-ups: one for push notifications and another for mobile data usage. Additionally, I receive the error message in the console as described above.

After performing a hot restart of my app, I can obtain my token, and everything works as expected. I believe this issue occurs because my code runs before I grant the app permission to use mobile data or Wi-Fi.

Here is my code for the push notification service, which is executed in the main() function. How can I resolve this issue when running my app for the first time no internet problem?

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

import '../modules/notifications/controllers/notifications_controller.dart';

final notificationServiceProvider = Provider<NotificationService>((ref) {
  return NotificationService(ref);
});

class NotificationService extends ChangeNotifier {
  final ProviderRef _ref;
  NotificationService(this._ref);

  String? token = "";
  PermissionStatus androidPermissionStatus = PermissionStatus.denied;
  late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;
  bool hasInitialPath = false;
  RemoteMessage? remoteMessage;

  Future<bool> registerNotification() async {
    NotificationSettings settings =
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
    notificationInit();
    var isAccept = settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized;
    if (isAccept) {
      debugPrint('User granted notification permission');
    } else {
      debugPrint('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }

    return isAccept;
  }

  notificationInit() async {
    //setup local notification
    await setupFlutterLocalNotifications();

    //get getFCMToken
    token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    debugPrint("device firebase token:$token");

    // called by receiving a message when app is background on Android
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    //Firebase messaging
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    // this is handle on foreground messages
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      handleMessage(message, isForegroundMessage: true);
    });

    // This trigger when app background and then click the notification
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      var _payload = message.data;
      var _notificationCont = _ref.read(notificationsControllerProvider.notifier);
      if (_payload["notification_type"] == "new_message") {
        // direct to chat page
        // _notificationCont.navigateToPageByNotificationPayLoadData(_payload["channel_url"]);
      } else {
        // direct to notification page, and then navigate to the page by notification id
        // _notificationCont.navigateToPageByNotificationId(_payload["notification_id"]);
      }
    });

    // await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    // await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

    //save the device token in the app
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((fcmToken) {
      token = fcmToken;
      debugPrint("device firebase token refreshed:$fcmToken");
    }).onError((err) {});

    //called by clicking on a message when app is terminated on Android and iOS
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) async {
      if (message != null) {
        hasInitialPath = true;
        remoteMessage = message;
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    handleMessage(message);
    debugPrint("Background message... ");
  }

  Future<void> handleMessage(RemoteMessage message, {isForegroundMessage = false}) async {
    if (message.notification != null || message.data['sendbird'] != null) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      bool isSendbird = message.data['sendbird'] != null;
      if (notification != null || isSendbird) {
        var sendBirdData = isSendbird ? jsonDecode(message.data['sendbird']) : {};

        if (!isForegroundMessage) {
          showFlutterLocalNotification(
            title: isSendbird ? sendBirdData['push_title'] ?? "" : message.notification?.title ?? "",
            body: isSendbird ? sendBirdData['message'] : message.notification?.body ?? "",
            //get the notification id from the message
            payload: isSendbird ? message.data['sendbird'] : json.encode(message.data),
          );
        }
        debugPrint(
            'Notification title: ${(isSendbird ? message.data['sendbird'] : json.encode(message.data)) ?? "fail to get title"}');
      }

      //this is for realtime update the status of the page when receive a message
      if (message.notification?.title != "" || isSendbird) {
        var reference = isSendbird ? jsonDecode(message.data['sendbird'])['message'] : message.notification?.title;
        // _ref.read(notificationsNotifierProvider.notifier).notifyOnMessageReceiver(reference);
      }
    } else if (message.data != null) {}
  }

  late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
  bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  //set up local notification
  Future<void> setupFlutterLocalNotifications() async {
    if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title
      description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(const InitializationSettings(
        iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(), android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_notification')));
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
  }

  //click notification navigate to particular page for foreground
  void showFlutterLocalNotification({required String title, required String body, String? payload}) async {
    void onDidReceiveNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
      var _payload = notificationResponse.payload;
      var _notificationCont = _ref.read(notificationsControllerProvider.notifier);
      if (_payload != null) {
        var _payloadJson = json.decode(_payload);
        if (_payloadJson["notification_type"] == "new_message") {
          // _notificationCont.navigateToPageByNotificationPayLoadData(_payloadJson["channel_url"]);
        } else {
          // _notificationCont.navigateToPageByNotificationId(_payloadJson["notification_id"]);
        }
      }
    }

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        const InitializationSettings(
            iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(), android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_notification')),
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse);

    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title
      description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
      importance: Importance.max,
    );
    debugPrint('notification payload1: $payload');
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      title,
      body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          importance: Importance.max,
          playSound: true,
          priority: Priority.high,
        ),
      ),
      payload: payload,
    );
  }
}
```

```
  Future<void> initialiseServices() async {
    await ref.read(notificationServiceProvider).registerNotification();
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    initialiseServices();
  }
```

[image]

[image]